# Can I use AutoRegression modelling for signal denoising?

Tags: python, signal-processing

As follows, my task is to use AR modeling to remove artifacts from noisy signals. Let's say I have ECG or EMG in raw data. On IEEE I have found that this is possible via Wavelet transform, Butterworth filters or Empirical mode decomposition.

https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/denoising-algorithms#Machine-learning-models

Raw EMG:

[image]

What exactly am I supposted to do with Auto Regression model? As I understand it right now it is used to forecast the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand it right now it is used to forecast the data.

Yes, that's a common case for `AR(p)` models; but in order to forecast, its parameters should be estimated and it is done over the observations you provide to it. Therefore you can have so-called "fitted values" and use them as the "denoised" version of the signal at hand. This is because `AR(p)` is this:

```
y_t = \phi_1 * y_{t-1} + \phi_2 * y_{t-2} + ... + \phi_p * y_{t-p} + e_t
```

where `\phi_j`'s are the AR parameters to be estimated and `e_t` is assumed to be a white noise with some variance. You can see this `e_t` as the noise on top of the underlying signal and therefore fitted values are somewhat denoised version.

Before the software implementation, we should note that `AR(p)` is modelling a wide sense stationary series so if a non-stationary behaviour exists (e.g. trend / seasonality), either it should explicitly be removed first (e.g. differencing), or implicitly removed (e.g. `ARI(p, d)` modelling).

Here is a deliberately noisy signal:

[image: noisy_AR]

and here is the fitted values of an `AR(2)` model on top of it:

[image: noisy_plus_denoised]

This is what I understand from the "denoising with AR models"; the `e_t` component in the assumed model represents the noise, and therefore fitted values give the "denoised" version.

As for the coding part: there are many ways to fit an `AR(p)` model with Python libraries, but possibly the most convenient one is through [`statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AutoReg`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AutoReg.html):

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg

model = AutoReg(your_data, lags=p)
result = model.fit()
fitted_values = result.fittedvalues
```

Deciding on the order of `AR(p)` is whole another issue, but one quick way is to look at the PACF plot of your data and see after which lag does it vanish e.g.

[image: pacf_ex]

This would indicate an `AR(2)` model.

Comment: is there any article in which I could read about it?

Comment: @yras8 About `AR` models? Here is one https://otexts.com/fpp3/AR.html

Comment: about use of AR modeling in denoising

Comment: @yras8 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7776204, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265025950_Vector_AR_filters_Extending_f-x_random_noise_attenuation_to_the_multicomponent_case

Comment: @yras8 I didn't really particularly know such a thing is in the literature. These are found by googling "AR modeling in denoising", sorry

Comment: In signal processing, ARMA filtering is a concept, you might want to look at that to see if there is a bridge to denoising, other than what I tried to answer here.