# no change in Autoregression model of signal, different implementations

Tags: python, machine-learning, signals

As told here:

[Can I use AutoRegression modelling for signal denoising?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799308/can-i-use-autoregression-modelling-for-signal-denoising/66803685?noredirect=1#comment118177524_66803685)

We can use AutoReg modelling to remove white noise from the signal. I have an deliberately noisy EMG signal as shown here and I want to remove high frequencies using AR.

[image]

In order to choose proper AR order i did plot a PACF chart :

[image]

The explanation from previous post says that implementation is pretty simple, what i did
The code is as follows:

```
model = sm.tsa.AutoReg(data.emg, 2).fit()
y_pred = model.model.predict(model.params, start=data.emg.index.min(), end=data.emg.index.max())
```

But I am not satisfied with result:

```
ax = pd.Series(data.emg).plot(color='lightgray')
pd.Series(y_pred).plot(color='black', ax=ax, figsize=(12, 10))
```

[image]

For me nothing have changed. Why is that? To ensure I tried different approach using Linear Regression with shifted values and result was also the same. What Am I doing wrong?